# Water level historical data for California

Tags: data-request, data.gov, json, csv

I am looking for data attesting for the **variation of fresh water availability** in California over the years (ideally 20+ years). For instance river levels, river throughput, wells levels.

If data is not available for California, similar USA data is OK too.

Bonus if the data can be easily used from Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with talking to people, you might want to contact the chief of the [Media & Public Information branch of the California Dept. of Water Resources](http://www.water.ca.gov/publicaffairs.cfm) at (916) 653-9712

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for hydrological data, the USGS has steam gauge data, which has a measure of the height of the water at various locations over time:

- http://water.usgs.gov/nsip/

For particulate data (which is more a water quality issue), you can try the EPA:

- http://www.epa.gov/storet/

Answer (score 1):

You can infer water availability from total precipitation over a given period. Google has a 115M dataset of weather stats for the US:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-gsod